# Comparing two infinite sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

So let A = { (a-b, a+b, 2ab) |a,b from R } and B = { (x-1, x+1, 2x | x from R}.
As I understand to be able to compare infinite sets you should try to make some sort of bijection between the 2 of them..but this is a bit confusing since in the first there are 2 variables.

Answer (score 0):

In what way are you wanting to compare these?

Each of these are subsets of $\Bbb R^3$ and have cardinality at most $\mathfrak{c}$ and have cardinality at least $\mathfrak{c}$ by simply looking at the first coordinate.  As such, they both have the same cardinality, namely $\mathfrak{c}$, the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$.  (*Remember that $|\Bbb R^3|=|\Bbb R|=\mathfrak{c}$*)

Further, you should be able to argue that the second is a subset of the first by setting $b=1$.  That these sets aren't equal should be clear by setting $b=2$.  The first set contains the element $(-2,2,0)$ while the second set does not (*all triples in the second set have the first two entries exactly two apart*).

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is simpler than it seems. Both the sets have $c=\mathbb{R}$ cardinality. This is easy to prove. Call $A$ the first set, you have an injection $j_A:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow A$ given by $j_A(x)=(x,x,0)$ (try to prove it) so $|\mathbb{R}|\leq|A|$, moreover $A\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ so $|A|\leq|\mathbb{R}^3|=|\mathbb{R}|$.
For the set $B$, define the injection $j_B:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow B$ by $j_B(x)=(x,x,2x)$ so we have $|B|\leq|\mathbb{R}|$ moreover - as before - $B\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ so $|B|\leq|\mathbb{R}^3|=|\mathbb{R}|$.
So (by Cantor-Bernstein theorem) we conclude that $|A|=|\mathbb{R}|=|B|$
It is worth noting that $|\mathbb{R}^3|=|\mathbb{R}|$ is a basic but non-obvious fact.